# Swift, print issue when use ? and ! variables

Tags: swift, variables, declaration

I got access error('fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value') when print variable p02. According to the error message, I still cannot understand the reason.

```
var p02:Person! = nil
var p03:Person? = nil

if (p02==nil)
{
    print("p02 is nil")
}
if (p03==nil)
{
    print("p03 is nil")
}
print(p03)
print(p02)
```

Anyone know why, 
Thanks

Comment: Because p02 is an *implicitly __unwrapped__ Optional* and p03 is just a normal Optional.

Comment: Why  declaration of p02 (var p02:Person! = nil ) is legal ?

Comment: Read the [Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309) chapter in the Swift guide, specifically the "Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals" part.

Answer (score 1):

cause it always tries to print p02 and p03 even if they are nil

try this

```
var p02:Person! = nil
var p03:Person? = nil

if (p02==nil)
{
    print("p02 is nil")
}else{
    print(p02)
}
if (p03==nil)
{
    print("p03 is nil")
}else{
    print(p03)
}
```